# angularjs 1 how to disabled selete option after submit form valid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms, angular1.6

Sorry if my question not well because i new in angular, please help me to drive to good solution and standard one.

here is my html form

```
<form ng-class="{'submitted': submitted}" name ="mybook" accept-charset="UTF-8" ng-submit="add_items()">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title-page">Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
          <md-select ng-model='title_page'>
            <md-option ng-repeat = "option in respons" ng-value = "{{option}}">{{option.name}}</md-option>
          </md-select>
    </div>
    <label for="type-page">Type_page</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
          <md-select ng-model='type_page'>
            <md-option ng-repeat = "option in responding" ng-value = "{{option}}">{{option.type_name}}</md-option>
          </md-select>
    </div>
    <label for="amount-page">Number Of Pages</label>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" ng-model="amount_page" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button ng-click="submitted= true;" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="material-icons">add</i> Add
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is my controller

```
$scope.add_items = function(){
    if($scope.mybook.$valid) {
        $scope.table_list_book.push({'nums':$scope.count_rows,'title':$scope.title_page.name,'type_name':$scope.type_page.type_name, 'page_num': $scope.amount_page});
        $scope.title_page.disabled = true; // i do like this to disable but not work

        //one more to stop user select old data on `type_page` but i no idea to do it
    }
}
```

I want:

- when my form submitted first time, `title_page` disabled(user can not change it in second or third, .. time more)
- and one more `type_page` user can not selected the same to previous data that submit ready.

Note:I do Ajax to add list to table not refresh page.

Thank for help with any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-disabled` in the `select`

For example,

```
<md-select ng-model='title_page' ng-disabled="isDisabled">
```

On submit:

```
$scope.isDisabled = true;
$scope.previousTypePage = '!' + $scope.type_page; // ! is to negate
$scope.type_page = ''; //Reset the value
//Store previous type_page value that should no longer show
//Use it in a filter
```

On responding:

```
<md-option ng-repeat = "option in responding | filter : previousTypePage">
```

Comment: can you detail more about `previousTypePage`

Comment: I don't know how to declare parameter `previousTypePage`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-disabled` for **title_page** as follows,

HTML

```
<form ng-class="{'submitted': submitted}" name ="mybook" accept-charset="UTF-8" ng-submit="add_items()">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title-page">Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
          <md-select ng-model='title_page' ng-disabled="isSubmited">
            <md-option ng-repeat = "option in respons" ng-value = "{{option}}">{{option.name}}</md-option>
          </md-select>
    </div>
    <label for="type-page">Type_page</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
          <md-select ng-model='type_page'>
            <md-option ng-repeat = "option in responding" ng-value = "{{option}}">{{option.type_name}}</md-option>
          </md-select>
    </div>
    <label for="amount-page">Number Of Pages</label>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" ng-model="amount_page" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button ng-click="submitted= true;" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="material-icons">add</i> Add
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Controller

use  [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) for rejecting previous selected value from dropdown option list

```
$scope.add_items = function(){
if($scope.mybook.$valid) {
    // do your stuff

    $scope.isSubmited = true;// this code will make your `title_page` disabled after first time submission
    $scope.responding = _.reject($scope.responding, function(obj){ return obj.id == $scope.type_page.id}); // this will reject the previously submitted value from dropdown option array
}}
```

> This kind of rejection from array will work only if no redirection happened. dropdown array will be get reloaded as initital, whenever page reloaded.